# Mesh selected, but can not enter Edit Mode

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I have [downloaded a model from Blend-Swap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/76261), that I wanted to study, to try and learn from it.
But as you can see in the screenshot, there is no Edit Mode. I selected a mesh in the outliner, but I noticed that it isn't outlined in the 3DView. Why would this happen?

[image]

Comment: Thats probably because that object is on another layer that is not selected, use right mouse button in 3D view to select the mesh you want to edit and then change to edit mode.

Comment: select the object labeled as ***rig***

Comment: Press "Reload Trusted" up at the top. Not sure if it's the culprit, but a good start.

Comment: thanks, it works if i select it in the 3dview :)
But I can't find it in the outliner :/
How the rig works, is the next thing I learn... need to watch some tutorials :)
Many thanks you two, Denis and cegaton :D

Comment: @NaioaiStudios if i click "Reload trusted" I get back to the initial state, without an outliner and the other views.

Comment: @StephaniePlatz I assume you want to pose the character, you need to enable layer 11 to see the rig and then select the rig and change to pose mode to move the bones

Comment: @Denis thanks :)
I only wanted to look, how he is modeled and colored, but I will watch some tutorials about animation, than I will give the posing a try :D